# changing singleinput code to dynamically add more input fields with same features in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, validation, dictionary, input

There was an input field set up, and it has many processes attatched to it.

these input fields are for "add member"

How can I make this code work so that I can add aditional fields into the react project?

Here is the code which had my problem in it.

My difficulty is in understanding the map function, in creating a different set of values for seperate input fields dynamically added (so they do not just change the same inpuit field) and in adapting the code to what worked when there was 1 input field.
so the

map( item, index)

the input fields reacting to different values.

the old code that worked with

```
     if (inviteSent && fields.email.value) {
          setInviteSent(false);
          console.log(inviteSent);
```

but does not work with

```
     if (inviteSent && fields[holder.length - 1].email.value) {
          setInviteSent(false);
          console.log(inviteSent);
```

---

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let CloneFields = {
    email: "",
    name: "",
  };

  let holder = [CloneFields];

  const [fields, setFields] = useState(holder);

  const emailChange = (e, index) => {
    holder[index].item = e.target.value;
    setFields(holder);
  };
  let FormInput = [""];

  const [inviteSent, setInviteSent] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inviteSent && fields[holder.length - 1].email.value) {
      setInviteSent(false);
      console.log(inviteSent);
    }
  }, [inviteSent, fields[holder.length - 1].email.value]);
  const addAnother = () => {
    holder = [holder + CloneFields];
    setFields(holder);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {fields.map((item, index) => (
        <input
          type="name"
          placeholder="Name"
          value={fields[index].item.value}
          onChange={emailChange}
        ></input>
      ))}
      <div onClick={addAnother}>add another +</div>

      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-mountain-b3cp2?file=/src/App.js

any advice is super useful, as i cant seem to get my head around the map function used in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your code made fairly little sense as-is, and I had to change quite some things – but in the end maybe you're looking for something like this? I've elided the "invite sent" bit since `setInviteSent` was never called anyway.

```js
const fieldsTemplate = {
  email: "",
  name: ""
};

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => [{ ...fieldsTemplate }]);

  const updateField = (e, field, index) => {
    const newData = [...data];
    newData[index] = { ...newData[index], [field]: e.target.value };
    setData(newData);
  };
  const addAnother = () => {
    const newData = [...data, { ...fieldsTemplate }];
    setData(newData);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <div>
          <input
            type="name"
            placeholder="Name"
            value={item.name}
            onChange={(e) => updateField(e, "name", index)}
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            value={item.email}
            onChange={(e) => updateField(e, "email", index)}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={addAnother}>Add another</button>

      <pre>
        <code>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help, sorry for the sloppy code/ recreation of code. You have given me exactly what i need to finishe the project :)